# Passing a parameter into the JQuery.slideUp() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slide my element up, then delete it. However I can't seem to pass the element ID into the callback that deletes it.

I can't hardcode the value since this has to be dynamic.

`insertedTemplates` is a collection of templates that are inserted into the page. When the user changed his/her option, a new element is inserted and the old one deleted.

The following will fail to delete the element because it is undefined:

```
    var elementId = insertedTemplates[i].id;
    $('#'+elementId).slideUp(400, function(elementId) {
        $('#'+elementId).remove();
    });
```

I found a post that suggests just passing the value in by adding it right after the function declaration.

This will immediately delete the element:

```
    var elementId = insertedTemplates[i].id;
    $('#'+elementId).slideUp(400, function() {
        $('#'+elementId).remove();
    }(elementId));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the element id. Use `$(this)` inside the callback.

```
var elementId = insertedTemplates[i].id;
$('#' + elementId).slideUp(400, function (elementId) {
    $(this).remove(); // <---- Use $(this)
});
```

`$(this)` inside the `slideUp` callback is the element on which the function is called.

Comment: That's embarrassingly easy. Thank you!